# Converting parametric equation of a line to polar equation

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, polar-coordinates

$2$ arbitrary points in the Cartesian plane describe a line with:

$$\vec r(t) = (1-t)P_1 + tP_2 = \langle x,y \rangle$$

What is the exact same line described in polar coordinates? My intuition tells me there is some kind of asymptote associated with this.

Comment: Are you allowed to chose the polar coordinates such that one of the points lies in the origin?

Comment: The equation can be written as $\vec{r}(t)=P_1+t(P_2-P_1)$, here the difference $P_2-P_1$ is a vector in the direction of the line connecting two points. So, to find the line in polar coordinates, you need to convert this vector to polar coordinates.

Comment: This is only a cartesian to polar conversion nothing more.

Comment: @klirk no, it must be an arbitrary representation

Comment: @hyprfrcb it's not as simple, because you need to solve for $r$ and $\theta$ in order to have a represenation in polar coordinates, and this involves the use of inverse trigonometric functions, which changes the range of acceptablke values

Comment: Are you looking for a polar equation in $r$ and $\theta$ for this line or do you simply wish to convert the parametric equation to polar form?

Comment: I mean, if you are just looking for a vector form in polar representation, we have $ \vec{r}(t)=\langle (1-t)r_1\cos\theta_1+tr_2\cos\theta_2,(1-t)r_1\sin\theta_1+tr_2\sin\theta_2\rangle$.

Comment: @amd I am looking for a polar parametric equation of $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ so it's not just putting it into polar form

Comment: [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#In_polar_coordinates) an expression for a line in polar coordinates.If you have $r$ in terms of $\theta$, it's pretty easy to parametrize

Comment: The expression itself involves $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $atan(y,x)$, where $x,y$ are from the expression given by  高田航 . This is a great equation, but it do not require any simplification.

Comment: [Here's another expression for a line in polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Line). If you can find the distance $r_0$ from the origin to the line and the angle $\theta_0$ of the perpendicular line, you have an explicit form for $r$ in terms of $\theta$

$$ r = r_0 \sec(\theta - \theta_0) $$

Answer (score 1):

An expression for a line in polar coordinates can given as

$$ r(\theta) = \rho_0 \sec (\theta - \theta_0) \tag{1} $$

where $\rho_0$ is the distance from the origin to this line and $\theta_0$ is the angle of the perpendicular line.

If the original line has the form $\boldsymbol{r}(t) = \boldsymbol{r}_0 + \boldsymbol{v}t$ where $\boldsymbol{r}_0 = (x_0, y_0)$ is an arbitrary point on the line and $\boldsymbol{v} = (a,b)$ is the direction vector, then the vector $\boldsymbol{\rho} = (\rho_0\cos \theta_0, \rho_0\sin\theta_0)$, which describes the point of tangency between the line and the circle of radius $\rho_0$, is given by

$$ \boldsymbol{\rho} = \boldsymbol{r}_0 - \left|\frac{\boldsymbol{r}_0\cdot \boldsymbol{v}}{\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}}\right|\boldsymbol{v} \tag{2} $$

The second term in $(2)$ is just the projection from the vector $\boldsymbol{r}_0$ onto the direction vector $\boldsymbol{v}$

The expression might be complicated, but you can't avoid trig functions in polar coordinates.

Comment: I appreciate the efforth but, this does not describe an arbitrary line, only lines tangent to the circles centered at the origin. take $p_0=0$ for example, your formla doesn't work for that case, and additionally, take a straight line from the origin (i.e $\vec r(\theta(t),r(t))=\langle C, t\rangle$) you can see these lines are not tangent to any circle (these are the libnes passing through the origin). So, you get a lot of lines with thses, but not all of them.

Comment: Those are special cases, which I assumed were trivial. A line through the origin just has $\theta = \textrm{constant}$. Every other line will work.